# Why does my character function crash?

Tags: c, string, function, return-value, substr

I'm working on a project meant to create functions to perform different  actions, but I'm having trouble implementing one of the functions.

```
int main()
{
    char str1[30] = "Hello";
    char str2[30] = "Goodbye old friend";
    char str3[30];

    char *p = strCopy(str3, "Annie");
    printf("(Annie) %s\n", p);

    p = strString(str3, "nn");
    printf("(nnie) %s\n", p);

    strCopy(str3, "HeloHellooo");
    p = strString(str3, "ello");
    printf("(ellooo) %s\n", p);

    return 0;
}

char *strCopy(char *s1, const char *s2)
{

   char *b = s1;

   while (*s2!='\0')
   {
      *s1 = *s2;
      s1++;
      s2++;
   }    
  *s1 = '\0';

  return b;

}


char *strString(const char *s1, const char *s2) // returns a string that starts with the characters in *s2. For example: char *strString ("Annie", "nn") should return "nnie".)
{
   char *test;
   char *b = test;  
   while (*s1 != '\0' && *s2 != '\0')
  {

      if (*s1 == *s2)
      {
         *test = *s1;
      }
      s1++;
      s2++;
   }

*test = '\0';      
return b;
}
```

I'm having trouble figuring out how to return a value in **char *strString** when constant integers are the only two parameters. When I try, the program crashes. Keep in mind that the parameters, function declarations, and what's inside main() have to be exactly as they're written. It's code given to me as part of the project. I can only manipulate what goes inside of the functions. I'm also not permitted to use arrays in any of my functions.

(The code inside of *strString is obviously not final. I'm just having trouble testing anything while I can't figure out how to return a value.)

Comment: the parameters to `strString` are pointers, not integers.  You will need to "cast away the const" in order to return, however (assuming this is supposed to have the same behaviour as the `strstr` function) you also have to rewrite the function body to actually produce the intended pointer first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside `strString` you use the uninitialized pointer `test`:

```
char *b = test;   // oops
```

...

```
*test = *s1;      // oops
```

You could start with:

```
char *test = NULL;
```

Then you could update `test` when you find your substring. At no stage do you want to write `*test =`, because you are not modifying either of the input strings, nor are you creating a new string. You should be returning a pointer which points into `s1` at the point where the substring can be found.

Comment: That makes sense. When I take that away and try to return test, however, it still crashes.

Comment: But `test` is still uninitialized. You have to initialize it to something - what exactly is it supposed to be?

Comment: If `strString::test` is supposed to be a buffer for a copy of s1, or somesuch, you need to malloc() test before you start writing to *test.

Comment: I added a description of what the function is trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! That's a lot of help